# Do we have cross platform solution to take a screenshot by .net 5?

Tags: .net-core, .net-5

Hello every one I am trying to take a scrrenshot

```cs
            using var bitmap = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0,
                    bitmap.Size,
                    CopyPixelOperation.SourceErase);
            }
```

But I see a warning about that it is only supported for the windows platform.
[image]
Do we have any cross-platform solution or separate solutions for Linux and MAC?